# Further terms of Taylor expansion for improved inequalities?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, recreational-mathematics, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

**Background:** We know the classical exponential inequality
\begin{align*}
1 + x \le e^x \qquad \text{or} \qquad x \le e^{x - 1}
\end{align*}
Taking $x_i = y_i/\overline{y}$, where $y_i \ge 0$ and $\overline{y}$ is the arithmetic mean, and multiplying out the second form, we yield
\begin{align*}
\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n}y_i}{\overline{y}^n} \le \exp\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i}{\overline{y}} - n\right) = 1
\end{align*}
And this yields a proof of the arithmetic-means and geometric-means (AM-GM) inequality.

**An improved exponential inequality:** We also have the exponential inequality
\begin{align*}
1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} \le e^x
\end{align*}
If we substitute $y = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6}$, we get the equivalent form
\begin{align*}
y \le e^{g(y)}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
g(y) = \left(\sqrt{9y^2 - 6y + 2} + 3y - 1\right)^\frac{1}{3} - \left(\sqrt{9y^2 - 6y + 2} + 3y - 1\right)^{-\frac{1}{3}} - 1
\end{align*}
is the inverse function expressing $x$ in terms of $y$.

**Can we derive other inequalities?** From here, there are many directions we may take with our given inequality, but due to the non-linear nature of $g(y)$, a direct trick of normalization as in the AM-GM proof will yield no immediate discoveries.

This post is meant to be very open to discuss possible inequality sharpenings from the cubic-Taylor expansion inequality above. Some observations:

1. $(g(y) + 1)^3 = -3(g(y) + 1)$
2. $[6y-2]_+^\frac{1}{3} - [6y-2]_+^{-\frac{1}{3}} - 1 < g(y) \le ([6y-2]_+ + 1)^\frac{1}{3} - ([6y-2]_+ + 1)^{-\frac{1}{3}} - 1$, where $[x]_+ = \max(x, 0)$.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

By your idea we can get for example the following inequality.

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers such that $abc=1$.
>
> Prove that:
> $$(a+b)^{a+b}+(b+c)^{b+c}+(c+a)^{c+a}\geq4(a+b+c).$$